# When I set State in function component I getting too many render error

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

UserAttemp.js

```
  const setModal = ({ item }) => {
    
    const perc = (item.score * 100) / item.total;
    console.log("perc", perc);
    if (perc >= 70) {
      setImagePath(smile);
    } else if (perc >= 40 && perc < 70) {
      setImagePath(dis);
    } else {
      setImagePath(sad);
    }
    setTotal(item.total);
    console.log("item_id",item.attempt_id);
    console.log("item_total",item.total)
    // setAttemp(item.attempted_question);
    setScore(item.score);
    setWrong(item.wrong);
    setSkip(item.skip);

    setModalVisible(true);
    // setboolThree(false);
    // setboolTwo(true);
  };
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.userAttemptItemContainer}
        onPress={() => setModal({ item })}
      >
        <View>
        <Text style={{alignSelf:'center',color:'black',textTransform:'uppercase'}}>{item.attempt_id}</Text>
          <View
            style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-around" }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.userAttempRenderText}>Score</Text>
            <Text style={styles.userAttempRenderText}>{item.score}</Text>
          </View>
   
  <Date_time
  
  item={item}/>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Loader bool={bool} />
      {!bool && (
        <View>
          <View style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
            <Text style={{ color: "black", fontSize: 20 }}>{title}</Text>
          </View>
          <FlatList
            data={attempt}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ height: 0, marginBottom: 90 }}></View>}
            ListEmptyComponent={() => <EmptyListMessage />}
          ></FlatList>
        </View>
      )}
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.ResultModalCenterView}>
          <View style={styles.ResultModalView}>
            <View style={styles.ResultModalClosebuttonCon}>
              <Pressable
                style={[styles.ResultModalButton, styles.ResultButtonClose]}
                onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
              >
                <Icon name="close" size={20} color="black" />
              </Pressable>
            </View>
            <ModalView
              score={score}
              total={total}
              wrong={wrong}
              title={title}
              skip={skipp}
              attempted={attempted}
              imagePath={imagePath}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};
export default UserAttemps;
```

Date_time.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View,Text } from 'react-native';
const Date_time=(props)=> {

    const [dateBool,setDateBool]=useState(props.item?false:true);
    const [timeBool,setTimeBool]=useState(props.item?false:true);
    if(props.item.start_date==props.item.end_date){
         setDateBool(true);
    }
    if(props.item.start_time==props.item.end_time){
        setTimeBool(true);
   }
   
    


  return (
    <View>
 {dateBool&&<View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'center',}}>
  <Text style={{color:'black',}}>Date:</Text>
  <Text style={{color:'black',marginLeft:5}}>{props.item.start_date}</Text>
 
  </View>}
  {!dateBool&&<View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'center',}}>
  <Text style={{color:'black',}}>Date:</Text>
  <Text style={{color:'black',marginLeft:5}}>{props.item.start_date}</Text>
  <Text style={{color:'black',marginLeft:5}}>{props.item.end_date}</Text>
  </View>}
  {/* <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'center'}}>
  <Text style={{color:'black'}}>Date</Text>
  <Text style={{color:'black'}}>{Date}</Text>

  </View> */}
 { timeBool&& <View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'center',}}>
  <Text style={{color:'black',}}>Time:</Text>
  <Text style={{color:'black',marginLeft:5}}>{props.item.start_time}</Text>
  
  </View>}
  {timeBool&&<View style={{flexDirection:'row',justifyContent:'center',}}>
  <Text style={{color:'black',}}>Time:</Text>
  <Text style={{color:'black',marginLeft:5}}>{props.item.start_time}</Text>
  <Text style={{color:'black',marginLeft:5}}>{props.item.end_time}</Text>
  </View>}
  </View>
  )
}
export default Date_time;
```

I am calling component in UserAttemp.js

I have made a component of Date_time in that I am trying to set state in the body of function component but i am getting too manay render error due to the useState hook

I want to set State in the body of function Date_time.jjs component how to set?

Answer (score 0):

Updating state outside the return function, makes it go in infinite loop. It will check the condition and update the state which will cause re-render then if will again check the condition and so on... it keeps re-rendering.

Remove the if statements and handle them in initial value of useState hook. Like-

```
const [dateBool,setDateBool]=useState(props.item?.start_date==props.item?.end_date ? true : props.item? false :true);

const [timeBool,setTimeBool]=useState(props.item?.start_time==props.item?.end_time ? true : props.item ? false:true);
```